# Add read replicas for SilverStripe website

Tags: php, postgresql, load-balancing, silverstripe

I've managed to get a stable load balanced front end servers that can scale horizontally quite well however the next bottle neck would be the db. There was a [blog post](https://www.silverstripe.org/blog/5-principles-to-optimise-your-website/) discussing scaling dbs horizontally however very little detail on it. I'm currently using PostgreSQL and so the only [plugin](https://github.com/nyeholt/silverstripe-splitdb) I've found wouldn't work.

Are my only options creating my own HAProxy or rewriting the PostgreSQL plugin to allow connections with read replicas?

I'm using AWS for all my hosting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly - I'd love to be corrected on this!

Having only had a quick look through some of the ORM classes in a SilverStripe 3.5 site, it looks like while the ORM *does support* multiple database connections (see `DB::get_conn` with argument for name) it is designed for specific use cases in mind. That is to say, you may have a module that needs to write to a specific database, so this would allow it to.

What you want is native and automatic support for this within the framework, so that all reads go to your slave(s) and writes go to your master. Unfortunately, it doesn't look like this comes out of the box. You might be able to achieve it by overloading a couple of the core SQL classes using the injector.

If you were to *try* it, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13666195/2812842) outlines how you could separate select statements out from the rest and run them through a different database connector.

As a quick example of how you might go at achieving this with `SQLSelect`, you will notice that it is injectable, which means you can easily overload it.

**File: mysite/_config/injector.yml**

```
Injector:
  SQLSelect:
    class: ReadOnlySQLSelect
```

You need to register a new database connection with the DB class:

**File: mysite/_config.php**

```
$readDatabaseConfig = array(/** define your DB credentials here, as with the default $databaseConfig **/);
if (!DB::connect($readDatabaseConfig, 'default_read')) {
    user_error('Failed to connect to read replica DB!', E_USER_ERROR);
}
```

Now, overload the `SQLSelect` class and replace the parts of it that call the DB class methods. This class inherits from `SQLExpression` which is the class the contains the methods you actually care about in this instance:

**File: mysite/code/ReadOnlySQLSelect.php**

```
class ReadOnlySQLSelect extends SQLSelect
{
    public function sql(&$parameters = array())
    {
        // Changed from SQLExpression: third parameter passed as connection name
        $sql = DB::build_sql($this, $parameters, 'default_read');

        if (empty($sql)) {
            return null;
        }

        if ($this->replacementsOld) {
            $sql = str_replace($this->replacementsOld, $this->replacementsNew, $sql);
        }

        return $sql;
    }

    public function execute()
    {
        $sql = $this->sql($parameters);
        // Changed from SQLExpression: skip DB::prepared_query since it doesn't allow
        // you to provide the connection name - replace it with its contents instead.
        $conn = DB::get_conn('default_read');
        return $conn->preparedQuery($sql, $parameters);
    }
}
```

**Note:** `SQLSelect::unlimitedRowCount` should technically be replaced where it calls `DB::prepared_query`, since the prepared query method calls `DB::get_conn` with no arguments, so will always return the default connection. You could replace the `DB::prepared_query` line the same as used above:

```
$conn = DB::get_conn('default_read');
$result = $conn->preparedQuery($sql, $innerParameters);
```

If you implement the above method, also change `new SQLSelect()` to `SQLSelect::create()`, otherwise you'll end up with some queries that still hit the master server because it'll bypass your class by not using the injector.

There's also an instance in `SQLConditionalExpression` that you should replace too (`::toSelect`) but that is likely to affect query transformations from other child implementations of that class, and you won't be able to do much about it without either (A) PRing a fix to the framework or (B) overloading all the other SQL* classes.

At this point you should have everything you need to route select queries to your `default_read` connection.

### Infrastructure

On the infrastructure side, you should be able to set up read replicas through the RDS console. When you do so it will provide you with a DNS endpoint for your replica node(s), which you can use in your `_config.php` to configure the connection to the read replica database.

---

If this works for you, you should create a module for it and put it up on GitHub - this would definitely be useful for others in future!

You may also consider making pull requests to the framework to add additional arguments to methods like `DB::prepared_query` to accept a connection name.

Also worth noting is that if you're using the mysqlnd database adapter you may be able to take advantage of [read/write splitting](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlnd-ms.rwsplit.php), implemented with some sort of injector overloading but all handled at a lower level than the application layer.

Comment: Thanks for the incredibly detailed answer. I think you've given me enough to go on to write a module to achieve the splitting. I had setup the infrastructure as a test but when I saw the different end point I realised it wouldn't do load balancing out of the box so was looking at alternative route.

Comment: It's been a while since I've used the read replica functionality in RDS, but I believe you can set up multiple read replicas that _should_ be load balanced by AWS. Worth investigating! Either way - having _a_ read replica would provide some benefits at least.

Comment: All I've read has said use HA Proxy which I believe is available as an AMI. I think doing it at the application level would be preferable as you can have more control as well especially when it becomes multi-region.

Comment: Hey @Rudiger - FYI I've been testing this on SS4 and it's actually unlikely to work at this stage, since the SS framework still has a lot of manual `DB::query()` statements in it. I've found that publishing a page fails at the moment due to the use of this rather than SQLSelect etc

Comment: Thanks Robbie, although it won't be load balanced nicely, could anything using `SQLSelect` be routed to the readonly and any manual `DB::query()` be routed to the default (i.e. the master)? While not the best it would still make it more scalable than currently.

Comment: I had that setup working in my tests but had some consistency issues in CMS. One option might be to only do this for frontend queries. Discuss further on GitHub if you'd like, issue is on te framework

Comment: https://github.com/silverstripe/silverstripe-framework/issues/7267 for people wanting a link to it.